# return javascript that needs to be executed, is json used for this?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to make a ajax call, that returns javascript that I then need to execute.

Can this be done using json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return a Javascript string, then call `eval()`.

Alternatively, you can add a `<script>` tag to the `<head>` instead of using AJAX.  (Unless you're sending a POST)